# R How to apply formula to certain columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
VisitID | No_Of_Visits | Store A | Store B | Store C | Store D|
   A1   |  1           |   1     |  0      |  0      |  0     |
   B1   |  2           |   1     |  0      |  0      |  1     |
   C1   |  4           |   1     |  2      |  1      |  0     |
   D1   |  3           |   2     |  0      |  1      |  0     |
   E1   |  4           |   1     |  1      |  1      |  1     |
```

In R how can I convert the Dataframe to count the % of visits by each Store Category, ie Visit count of each Store divided by No_Of_Visits on a visit level? Expected result:

```
VisitID | No_Of_Visits | Store A | Store B | Store C | Store D|
   A1   |  1           |   100%  |  0      |  0      |  0     |
   B1   |  2           |   50%   |  0      |  0      |  50%   |
   C1   |  4           |   25%   |  50%    |  25%    |  0     |
   D1   |  3           |   67%   |  0      |  33%    |  0     |
   E1   |  4           |   25%   |  25%    |  25%    |  25%   |
```

Are there ways in dplyr? or must sapply function be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `prop.table`

```
df[-c(1:2)] <- prop.table(as.matrix(df[-c(1:2)]), 1) * 100
df

#  VisitID No_Of_Visits   Store.A Store.B  Store.C Store.D
#1      A1            1 100.00000       0  0.00000       0
#2      B1            2  50.00000       0  0.00000      50
#3      C1            4  25.00000      50 25.00000       0
#4      D1            3  66.66667       0 33.33333       0
#5      E1            4  25.00000      25 25.00000      25
```

---

In `tidyverse`, we can get the data in long format, divide the values by  `No_Of_Visits` and get data back in wide format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Store')) %>%
  mutate(value = paste0(round(value/No_Of_Visits * 100, 2), "%")) %>%
  pivot_wider()
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(VisitID = structure(1:5, .Label = c("A1", "B1", 
"C1", "D1", "E1"), class = "factor"), No_Of_Visits = c(1L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 4L), Store.A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), Store.B = c(0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 1L), Store.C = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Store.D = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```